# Centos 6 - Multiple ISCSI Initiator Nodes

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, linux-networking, iscsi

We recently purchased a second iscsi target, and I am trying to have them both mounted on one of our hosts. Each would be mounted to different directories. Is it possible to do something like this:

/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi

```
InitiatorName=iqn.2016-04.com.example.iscsi-1:testing1
InitiatorName=iqn.2017-01.com.example.iscsi-2:new-testing1
```

Right now when I attempt to log into the second iscsi target I am told that the first.

```
iSCSI Initiator Node: iqn.2016-04.com.example.iscsi-1:testing01 is not authorized to access iSCSI target portal group: 1
```

Do I need a second nic in the server? Or is this a case of me doing something weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the first and only initiator name to the acl on the new target.

Comment: Thanks! Entirely my misunderstanding as to the true purpose of InitiatorName setting.  It's working now since I created an acl for the InitiatorName listed first.